# How use single Log4net configuration (separate file or inside app.config) for all my project?

Tags: c#, log4net

Could someone guide me trough example or an URL to achieve my need.

Project description :

- 3 DLL (classe library) (C# 2.0)
- windows application (C# 2.0)

Need :
Use only one log4net configuration to log events/Erros/ ... (either i'am in DLL or in windows application)

N.B = it'll be useful for me if the 3 external dll can read configuration from windows application app.config file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally speaking, every class library called from the 'windows application' uses configuration files deployed by windows application project. Thanks to that, current configuration depends on the starting project (could be wf, wpf, web...).

just remember to set the additional config files to be deployed with the application

```
  Properties -> Copy to output folder -> Copy Always
```

This behavior is quite easy to understand if you look into the deployed application directory. It contains all the projects' as dlls and all the other files configured to be copied to the final folder. By default each project has the same access to these files as they are all in the same location. If they for example look for "log4net.xml" they will find the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the **Repository - SimpleModule** example:

> The SimpleModule is a class library that is intended to be used as
>   part of the SimpleApp example, This class library uses the
>   log4net.Config.Repository attribute to create a separate configuration
>   space from other assemblies.
>
> This example is available for the following platforms and languages.
>   If a version is not available for your chosen platform and language
>   combination then select the nearest platform for the appropriate
>   language.  MONO 1.0: C#  .NET 1.0: C#, VB  .NET 1.1: JScript.NET 
>   SSCLI 1.0: C#
>
> This library is intended to be used as part of the SimpleApp example.

The following example is only available in the **log4net source download**, not on-line. To obtain the example download the log4net source release.